# In which worship are these organs mentioned in YajurVeda offered to Lord Shiva?

Tags: scripture, shiva, vedas, yajur-veda, yajna

Association of various bodily organs to Lord Shivas AsthaMurty form (8 forms) are mentioned in YajurVeda. Here is passage from YajurVeda Taittariya Samhita 1.4.36:

> चित्तम् संतानेन भवं यक्ना रुद्र तनिम्ना पशुपतिम् स्थूलहृदयेनाग्नीम् हृदयन रुद्रं लोहितेन शर्वम् मतस्नाभ्याम् महादेवम् अन्तःपार्श्वेनौषिष्ठहनम् शिंगीनिकोश्याभ्याम् ।। (Yajurveda 1.4.36) 
>  
>   Chitta with the **sinew,** Bhava with the **liver,** Rudra with the **taniman,** Pashupati with the **thick heart,** Agni with the **heart,** Rudra with the **blood,** Sarva with the **kidneys,** Mahadeva with the **intestinal flesh,** him that slayest most quickly with the entrails.

**Are these parts associated with offerings of animal organs of the sacrificed animals of Yajna?** Or it is about association with living organs like, Bhava is associated with liver, Pashupati with thick heart etc.. etc...?

**If it is about offering of animal parts from Vedic Yajna, then in which Yajnas are these parts offered?** 

As a sidenote I guess that these are offered also in Ashwamedha Yajna, because as discussed in [answer here,](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17268/where-does-ramayana-state-ashwamedha-yajna-is-intended-for-worship-of-lord-rudra/17269#17269) Ramayana states 'Ashwamedha Yajna is the highest worship of Rudra.'

Comment: I think worshipping of Shiva with Sri Rudram also have such verses to offer such parts to /shiva. It may be done during perfect Rudrabhishekam.

Comment: @Pandya Where do you find such verses in Sri Rudram, I do not seem to find any such...